# Condition under which a ring is isomorphic to a right ideal.

Tags: ring-theory, modules, module-isomorphism

**Defintion:** an element $a\in R$ is said to be right regular if, there is no nonzero element $b\in R$ such that $ab=0$.

**My Questuion:** Let $R$ be a ring with identity. Then $R$ is $R$-isomorphic to a right ideal $I$ of $R$ (as a right $R$-module) if and only if $I=aR$ for some right regular element of $R$.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more what do you intent to do in this new context?

Comment: Does $R$ has 1?

Comment: The isomorphism is determined by where it sends $1$, which has to be a regular element by your previous result. Being essential is rather unrelated (or so it seems to me?$) so I doubt there is a great way to weave it in other than simply stipulating it outright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have find a solution of my problem which is as follows:

First suppose that there exists an $R$-isomorphism $f:R\rightarrow I$. Let $a=f(1)\in R$.
Then $ab=0\implies f(1)b=0\implies f(b)=0\implies b=0$ for any $b\in R$, as $f$ is one-one.  Let $s\in I$ then there exist $r\in R$ such that $s=f(r)=f(1)r=ar$, as $f$ is onto.
Thus $a$ is a right regular element such that $I=aR$.

Conversely suppose that there exists a right regular element $a\in R$ such that $I=aR$. Define a map $f:R\rightarrow I$ by $f(r)=ar,\forall r\in R$. Then $f$ is an $R$-isomorphism.